# Passing lines from the text file of a list of files to or as arguments

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a file which has two file names per row, like this:

```
file1.fastq.gz file2.fastq.gz
...
file9fastq.ga file10fastq.gz
```

How can I pass the two names as arguments for a script?

Comment: Each **line** of the input file should be use as parameters to the script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a `while read` loop:

```
while read -r file1 file2 trash; do
  something with "$file1" and "$file2"
done < /path/to/input_file
```

This will read your input file line by line, setting `file1` and `file2` with the first and second columns respectively.  `trash` is probably unnecessary but I like to include it to handle things you may encounter such as:

```
file1.fastq.gz file2.fastq.gz foo
```

If your file contained a line like the above and you did not include the `trash` variable (or one similar), your `file2` variable would be set to: `file2.fastq.gz foo`

Comment: I tried `while read -r file1 file2 trash; do BatchTester $file1 $file2 done < configseparated` but instead of executing it what I get is space too keep writing instead of execution
however the sheel then only o gives me the opportunity to keep writing

Answer (score 4):

`xargs` is another way, if your file format is exactly as you say: two whitespace-separated fields per line (noting the `...` ellipsis).

```
< input xargs -n2 ./script-here
```

... will read the file named `input` line-by-line and pass two arguments to `./script-here`.

You can rearrange the redirection:

```
xargs -n2 ./script-here < input
```

... if it makes better intuitive sense to you.